# How to compare a string variable against a literal in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to do an OS check in my .zshrc. I can't get the string comparison against Ubuntu to match correctly when running on Ubuntu.

Snippet:

```sh
function get_linux_distro()
{
    echo `awk -F= '/^NAME/{print $2}' /etc/os-release`
}

function is_os_ubuntu()
{
    set -x
    local dist=`get_linux_distro`
    if [[ ${dist} = "Ubuntu"* ]]; then  # <<< string comp
        echo "UBUNTU"
        return 0
    else
        echo "BLAHHHH"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Output:

```sh
❯ is_os_ubuntu
+is_os_ubuntu:4> get_linux_distro
+get_linux_distro:3> awk '-F=' '/^NAME/{print $2}' /etc/os-release
+get_linux_distro:3> echo '"Ubuntu"'
+is_os_ubuntu:4> local dist='"Ubuntu"'
+is_os_ubuntu:5> [[ '"Ubuntu"' = Ubuntu* ]]  # <<< don't match due to quotes??
+is_os_ubuntu:10> echo BLAHHHH
BLAHHHH
+is_os_ubuntu:11> return 1
```

Note: I've added the bash tag since I'm lead to believe this is the same in both and bash has more visibility.

Comment: If you look at your output you are saving a name that includes the `'"'` as part of the variable, e.g. `'"Ubuntu"'` and you are correct it doesn't match due to quotes. You are better served using `[[ var =~ REGEX ]]` so you can match against `\"Ubuntu.*$` where the name may (or may not) include additional text after `"Ubuntu`. To do so you can use `[[ $dist =~ \"Ubuntu.*$ ]]`. You need to escape the `'"'` as a quirk of `[[ var =! expression ]]` is that if `expression` is quoted, it is treated as a string instead of a Regex.

Comment: A better use of `awk` may be to remove to double-quotes completely, e.g. `dist=$(awk -F= '/^NAME/{gsub(/\x22/,"",$2); print $2}'` or if you prefer octal, use `\042`.

Comment: Please do not ask XY question. Are you interested in how to correctly compare a string variable or do you want to check if linux is ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to correctly compare a string variable against a litteral in zsh

Remove the `*` or quote it, otherwise, it's parsed as a glob expression. You are correctly comparing it.

```
[[ ${dist} = "Ubuntu" ]]
```

Because your string is not `Ubuntu`, but `"Ubuntu"`, it's not equal and works correctly.

Please do not ask XY questions.

From `man os-release`:

> The basic file format of os-release is a newline-separated list of **environment-like shell-compatible variable assignments**. [...]

Source the file in shell and output the variable, preferably in a subshell.

```
get_linux_distro() {
    sh -c 'source /etc/os-release; echo "$NAME"'
}
```

Do not use backticks `. Prefer `$(...)`.

Do not use: `echo $(something)` - it's a useless use of echo, like `echo $(echo $(echo $(something)))`. Just do the thing you want to do, without echo.

Check your scripts with HTTP://shellcheck.net.

Comment: Thank you for the general tips. I did not intend to ask an XY question. I was asking only about the string comparison as that was the crux of my issue. However, your additional advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While the comments you got, and the answer given by KamilCuk. are of course correct, one alternative worth considering would be to use `[[ $dist:l == *ubuntu* ]]` for the test. This would test whether `dist` contains `ubuntu` as a substring, case insensitively.